# How to handle failed skill events?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm implementing skill lifecycle events using ["Skill Events"](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/skill-events-in-alexa-skills.html). Going through the docs can't find anything that mentions what should I respond with for these events. Closest I found was:

> Alexa will attempt to redeliver events if an acknowledgement is not
>   sent by the skill service, for up to one hour. If the skill service
>   receives an event, and the skill service sends an acknowledgment in
>   response, this event must then be managed by the skill service. In
>   either case, the skill service cannot, at a later time, retrieve past
>   events from Alexa.
>
> [Source](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/skill-events-in-alexa-skills.html#delivery-of-events-to-the-skill)

What does it imply, an empty 200 response? What do if something fails. Should I return a 200 status with a formatted error similar to [Alexa ErrorResponse](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-errorresponse.html)?

As the skill event data schema is different from typical Alexa events, I presume it's different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far by just playing with the responses, if I return an empty 200 response, Alexa understands that I acknowledged the request and doesn't send it anymore.

If something fails I respond with a 400 status and plaintext error msg. Then I received the request again later.

Also be sure to save the `timestamp` from either `AlexaSkillEvent.SkillEnabled` or `AlexaSkillEvent.SkillAccountLinked` requests with the user, so you can validate if the repeatedly sent events are valid if something isn't right.